# Iterate over a jQuery collection without having to rebuild the jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator

```
$(".item").each (i, elt) ->
    $(elt).attr("href")
    # ...
```

Doing `$(elt)` is necessery to get the jquery object. Is there a way to iterate over a jquery collection, without having to rebuild the jquery object?

Comment: If you're just after the `href` attribute, why not use `elt.href`?

Comment: Because it's a totally random example, I need the jquery object.

Comment: You don't have a jQuery object of each element in the first place. When you use `$(".item")`, it basically creates an array of DOM elements. So you're not rebuilding a jQuery object. You have one major jQuery object that encompasses all the elements. When you need to access one, you have to wrap it as a jQuery object if you want the jQuery methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doing $(elt) is necessery to get the jquery object.

Yes.

> Is there a way to iterate over a jquery collection, without having to rebuild the jquery object?

No. Because the jQuery object you have is a set of all of the matched elements. To use the jQuery methods on individual elements, you need to get a jQuery object containing just the individual element you want to act on. In a loop, that means wrapping your `elt` (or `this`, as both are the same DOM element).

For lots of things, though, you don't *need* jQuery methods. Your example is one of those things, just use `elt.href` directly:

```
$(".item").each (i, elt) ->
    var someVar = elt.href;
    # ...
```

The [DOM2 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) and the newer [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) both list lots of reflected properties you can use directly. `id`, for instance, is one in particular people frequently use. You see `$(this).attr("id")` a lot where `this.id` would be sufficient (and more efficient, although it's extremely rare that the efficiency matters).

Comment: Yeah but I mean jQuery could potentially have chosen to pass the actual jQuery object to the callback.

Comment: @Robin: Right, they could have -- but they didn't, probably because it would have meant creating a lot of jQuery objects people wouldn't necessarily use, causing unnecessary memory churn. This way, people can create the objects (or not) as necessary.

Comment: @Robin it would have to make one first

Comment: Yep, I get it now, I forgot the jquery collection was actually just a list of dom elements...

Comment: @Robin jQuery just gets the elements from the DOM and presents them to you. It's up to you to wrap them in a jQuery object to access jQuery methods. Like TJ said, it would be a bunch of overhead to create jQuery objects for every matched element and store it. It makes more sense to store the minimum (what is actually retrieved) and leave it up to the developer to add to it. You seem to already know/understand this, I just wanted to chime in

Comment: That DOM2 spec link alone seems very useful. Bookmarking, thanks.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Part of my standard reference links list, no question. Also DOM2 Core, DOM3 Core, the events specs, etc. All available here: http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cache the jQuery object then select by index.

```
var $items = $(".item");

$items.each(function(i) {
    $items.eq(i).doStuff();
});
```

Comment: Note that this will spew jQuery objects as well, albeit in a different way. `eq` doesn't (and cannot) cache its return value.