# Retrieving the HTML in one go - and iterated clone - of a jQuery collection?

Tags: jquery, html, iteration

Consider this example:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
#srclist {
  display:none;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
ondocready = function() {
  // get the children of srclist in a jQuery object:
  var jqChildren = $("#srclist").children();
  // .log outputs: jqChildren Object { 0: <li#litem1>, 1: <li#litem2>, 2: <li#litem3>, length: 3, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → test_jq_children_html.htm }
  console.log("jqChildren", jqChildren);

  // get the HTML of this collection
  var jqHTMLstr = jqChildren.html();
  // expecting output: "<li id="litem1">Test Item 1</li>\n<li id="litem2">Test Item 2</li>\n<li id="litem3">Test Item 3</li>"
  // but .log outputs: jqHTMLstr Test Item 1
  console.log("jqHTMLstr", jqHTMLstr);

  // iterate
  // $(elt) is necessery to get the jquery object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688899/
  //~ $(jqChildren).each(function( index, elt ) { // OK
  jqChildren.each(function( index, elt ) { // OK
    // .log outputs 0 <li id="litem1">Test Item 1</li>
    //~ console.log(index, $(elt)[0].outerHTML); // OK
    console.log(index, elt.outerHTML); // OK, (but TypeError: elt[0] is undefined)
  });
}
$(document).ready(ondocready);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <h1>Testing ...</h1>

  <ul id="srclist">
    Some invalid HTML here
    <li id="litem1">Test Item 1</li>
    Some more invalid HTML here
    <li id="litem2">Test Item 2</li>
    <li id="litem3">Test Item 3</li>
  </ul>

  <ol id="dstlist">
  </ol>

</body>
```

I am informed by `console.log` that

```
var jqChildren = $("#srclist").children();
```

... contains a collection (like an array, but it's an object) of jQuery objects; how could I get the HTML string of this jQuery collection in one go?

The problem is that `jqChildren.html()` returns only the inner HTML of the first child/element in the collection - but I'd need the outer HTML of the collection (which would be the inner HTML of the parent, but we don't have one here).

I could also iterate over `jqChildren` using `.each()` and concatenate a string from `.outerHTML` of the elements - but I'd rather not iterate, but instead retrieve the HTML in one go. Is there a command I could use for that?

Sub-question - if I wanted to add `.clone()`s of `elt` in the `jqChildren.each()` loop to the `<ol id="dstlist">`, what is the recommended way of doing that? On the other hand, can you do an assignment of a `jqChildren` clone directly on jQuery object level as "children" of `#dstlist`, i.e. something like pseudocode `$("#dstlist").htmlObject(jqChildren.clone())`? (just the trivial use of `.html()` didn't work for me)